# problem with a little ruby script

Tags: ruby

i just began learning ruby.
now im trying to code a little script which plays the montyhall problem
i got a problem with the last line of the code

```
numgames = 10000 # Number of games to play 
switch = true # Switch your guess?
wins = 0
numgames.times do doors = [0, 0, 0] # Three doors! 
doors[rand(3)] = 1 # One of them has a car! 
guess = doors.delete_at(rand(3)) # We pick one of them!
doors.delete_at(doors[0] == 0 ? 0 : 1) # Take out one of the remaining doors that is not a car! 
wins += switch ? doors[0] : guess end
puts "You decided #{switch ? "" : "not "}to switch, and your win % is #{wins.times ()/numgames}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `wins` is an integer so you don't need `.times` or `.size`, you do, however, want `.to_f` to force things into floating point mode:

```
wins.to_f / numgames
```

And if you want a percentage, then you'll have to multiply by 100:

```
wins.to_f / numgames * 100
```

You should also properly indent your code for readability and break things up with line breaks to make it easier to read and easier for the parser to figure out:

```
numgames = 10000 # Number of games to play
switch = true # Switch your guess?
wins = 0
numgames.times do
    doors = [0, 0, 0] # Three doors!
    doors[rand(3)] = 1 # One of them has a car!
    guess = doors.delete_at(rand(3)) # We pick one of them!
    doors.delete_at(doors[0] == 0 ? 0 : 1) # Take out one of the remaining doors that is not a car!
    wins += switch ? doors[0] : guess
end
puts "You decided #{switch ? "" : "not "}to switch, and your win % is #{100 * wins.to_f / numgames}"
```

Answer (score 2):

In the last line replace

```
wins.times ()
```

with

```
wins
```

`times` returns `Enumerator`, which doesn't play well with division.

Comment: Thanks! But im still getting a syntax error. monty.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ')'
...nd your win % is #{wins.size ()/numgames}"

Comment: Are your parentheses balanced?

Comment: Does that mean that every parantheses is correctly opened and closed? Then yes!

Comment: `wins` is an integer. Why call `times` or `size` on an integer?

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

First, `wins` and `numgames` are integers, and integer division returns an integer:

```
irb(main):001:0> 6632 / 10000
=> 0
```

So, change `wins = 0` to `wins = 0.0`. This will force a floating point division, which will return a floating point answer.

Second, `wins` is a number, not an array. So get rid of `wins.times()` *and* `wins.size()`. Both are wrong.

With these two changes in place, I consistently get around 66% wins, which just goes to show that [Marilyn vos Savant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marilyn_Vos_Savant) is *way* smarter than I am.